# Compile Error: 'Expected variable or procedure, not module'

Tags: excel, vba

How do I explain the 'expected variable or procedure, not module' error in this instance?

Code:

Routine -

```
Sub WTS_9_Click()
    Call Module1
End Sub
```

Module -

```
Sub Rec_9_Click()
```

The error came about because I learnt a better way to structure code by calling in sub-routines through modules. I have activated the Solver, carefully renamed Modules - set variables, functions and other objects are not interfering - and, yet, it remains stuck. Ideas to help explain the jam would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont `Call` a module, you `Call` the routine, and the word `Call` is optional.

You probably want this:

```
Sub WTS_9_Click()
    Rec_9_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, yes, OK, calling passes through the module. Gotchya.

Answer (score 1):

Within you module you need to declare (public) routines, i.e.

Module (named Test)

```vb
Public Sub TestMessage()
    MsgBox "Test"
End Sub
```

Then in your code (i.e. events) you can call this routine within the module:

```vb
Sub Button_Click()
    call TestMessage
    call Test.TestMessage ' you can skip the module name if routine name is unique
End Sub
```